# Is there a way to use the System.Windows.Automation library to find the point of the html element firefox by process?

Tags: vb.net, firefox, automation, process, element

I have used `System.Windows.Automation` to find out the current url of Firefox in windows process. Is there any way to find out the location of an html element in firefox? I need any one idea for this project. Thank you very much

Comment: And then what? What is it that you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: Find point x and y on screen windows